# Hidden JavaScript error

Tags: javascript

When i navigate across the application, i get a javascript error in my taskbar but gets disapperard immediately before i can identify what is the error about

The error appears in IE and i don't see anything in FireBug

Comment: Firebug is *not* an IE extension. Are you using Firebug Lite?

Comment: i know firebug is for firefox, i am not using firebug lite...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit `F12` and find the **Script** tab. The **Console** subtab should provide the error info.

Answer (score 7):

Download Firebug for Firefox.  Ensure it is enabled, and check out the console.  Javascript errors will appear in red, here.

Comment: +1 for recommending firebug. every javascript developer should be using it.

Comment: @Spudley - Chrome has some very useful tools now, firebug isn't the only show in town :)

Comment: @Nick: Firebug is still the best. ;)  (but agreed, there are other good tools...)

Comment: @Spudley - Opinion, not fact :) I use Chrome for daily development, each have their strong points.  Also Firebug **for firefox** as the answer above points to may not solve this issue, or show any errors at all.  For example a trailing comma is fine in Firefox, not in IE.

Answer (score 0):

Which application? Which browser are you using? Kindly provide further details

Safari and Chrome come with their built-in developer tools so does IE. As mentioned firefox has Firebug plugin and the venkman debugger

Comment: Generally these kind of messages goes as comments not as answers.

Comment: apologies Teja, fired away prematurely